# Wifi card running hotter on Arch than other distros

Tags: networking, arch-linux, kernel, wifi, temperature

So recently I've tried using arch because why not, and I really like my setup, the only thing that is bothering me, is the fact that the wireless card is running hotter than other distros (45°C on arch and 35°C on other distros), tried Fedora, Ubuntu, Pop OS, elementary OS, and only Arch seems to have the problem. Also notice hotter temps on Manjaro and Endeavour OS, both arch based distributions. All the distros were using the same kernel driver `iwlwifi`, but I only have this problem on arch based distros.

My wifi Card:

- Intel corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
- kernel: 5.9.6-arch1-1

What I have tried:

- configuring power_save on iwlwifi config before boot.
- configuring power save on `NetworkManager`
- Installing intel microcode
- Regulatory domain
- downloading iwlwifi from AUR

Nothing so far have work.

When running on battery the temps are normal, only happens when connected to AC, so maybe there is a way to leave battery config when plugged in?

I've searched a lot and follow arch wiki tutorials but nothing seems to work, and I'm really noob when it comes to linux firmware